# Get permission denied when accessing node.js application azure app services

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

I have deployed my node.js application on Azure app services I get below error:

```
{ Error: listen EACCES: permission denied development
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1262:19)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1425:5)
at Function.listen (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Server.start (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:33:18)
at new Server (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:30:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:101:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
code: 'EACCES',
errno: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'listen',
address: 'development',
port: -1 } 'Error: listen EACCES: permission denied development\n    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _  listen2] (net.js:1262:19)\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your port like below in your app.js or server file where you set the port.

```
 var port = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3000;
```